# Git show lines of code per author per file

Tags: git

So for my project I need to show an individual person's contribution as lines of code on a per file basis. What I have tried:

```
git-quick-stats
```

This shows the total insertions and deletions per user as:

```
 Mayank Rikh <____@____>:
      insertions:    4680   (41%)
      deletions:     2389   (53%)
      files:         266    (44%)
      commits:       43 (39%)
      lines changed: 7069   (44%)
      first commit:  Sat Oct 31 20:48:23 2020 +0000
      last commit:   Thu Dec 10 22:41:05 2020 +0530
```

But I can't seem to find an argument to list them all by file.

So to see on a per file basis, I tried:

```
git log --author="Mayank Rikh" --pretty=tformat: --numstat
```

This gave a result quite close to what I expected but when I tried total the count of insertions from the above command, it resulted in just 1500 insertions which is different from the `git-quick-stats`.

Why is that? Which is the real number?

Comment: You can delete and add several time the same lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "real" number. It's all pretty fuzzy to begin with and while a little interesting you simply aren't going to get "genuine" numbers no matter what you do. For example, do you include whitespace changes or exclude them? How do you handle whole file deletions? What if there are co-authors? How do you handle merges and squashes? At some point it devolves into something akin to the [coastline paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) in that the more questions you ask, the more complicated these measurements become.

What's more meaningful is to pick a single algorithm and then track changes over time. You'll get some sense of changes in developer contributions over time. It won't by exactly accurate, but comparing the results of different algorithms isn't useful at all.

For example, consider a scenario where User A changes 10 lines of code, resulting in -2/+12. Then User B undoes that change, resulting in -12/+2.

Do those changes cancel out, to where User A and User B each have 0 changes? Or should you count them separately?

Consider another scenario where User A adds 100 new lines of code to a module, resulting in +100. Then User B deletes the module, resulting in -300.

Does User A get credit for those 100 lines? Does User B get credit for all 300 lines that were removed?

Whatever algorithm you choose for counting changes, it should not be a surprise if a different algorithm yields very different results.